# An electronics question tangentially related to vehicular use got migrated

Tags: support

See: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/616167/revisions

It was a question that boils down to: "I got this fuel cell with a 0-100 ohm fuel sender. But my vehicle's control unit needs 450-100 ohm input. I can't mess with the sender. How do I adapt it?"

It's an electronics question. There are no off-the-shelf solutions, and this requires a circuit that emulates a 450-100 ohm resistor, based on the input from a 0-100 ohm fuel sender.

It got migrated to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair (https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/88464/understanding-ohms-resistance-and-how-to-tell-a-fuel-float-gauge-to-tell-the-o#616173).

Sure, the problem is *presented* in the context of an automotive application, but it requires a custom solution that is entirely in the purview of electrical engineering. The best I can tell, it appears to be off-topic in MVM&R, since MVM&R is not about electrical circuit design.

I consider the migration to be unwarranted. At best, it's presumptuous in assuming that the asker should perhaps look for some "other" solution, where no other solution exists: they got the stuff, they gotta make it work somehow.

Answer (score 2):

The question is more searchable and better suited for motor vehicles and is not off topic there, so it was moved. In addition people that work more with vehicle sensors can provide more insight on compatibility or solutions that may not be apparent to a circuit designer.